# Meaning of different tenses for 3pm

Tags: tense

Am I right that:

> I go there on 3pm

denotes I go there regularly on 3pm

> I will go there on 3pm

denotes I have a plan to go there on 3pm

> I will be going there on 3pm

denotes that the action `will be going` is carry on on 3pm

Comment: All are wrong; we use **at** with times, not **on**. Otherwise the verbs are OK, although your third 'denotes...' is poorly written - better, 'denotes that the action will be in progress at 3pm'.

Answer (score 3):

(Following on Michael Harvey's comment)

As you surmise, **I go there at 3 pm** points to a regular arrangement and would generally (but not necessarily) be followed by an indication of the interval, such as: **on Wednesdays, on weekdays, each day**.

**I will/shall go there at 3 pm** points to the intention of the speaker. It leaves open the question of whether the speaker will leave for the destination or arrive there at 3 pm.

There is very little difference between the statement above and: **I will be going there at 3 pm.** Much of the time they are interchangeable and the choice will depend on preference and context.

However, there are circumstances where they may mean different things.

> I fly to Boston at 3 pm

means that my flight to Boston leaves at 3 pm.

> I will be flying to Boston at 3 pm

may mean that my flight to Boston departs at 3 pm or it may mean that I will be in the air en route at Boston at 3 pm.

So if someone asks you what you will be doing tomorrow afternoon at 3 pm, you may reply: **I will be (somewhere over the Atlantic) flying to Boston**.